# JQuery need to push down page content on WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a unique situation and I will do my best to explain what I am trying to accomplish. I hope I am clear and someone can provide the framework to execute this.

Using WordPress, I would like to inject a landing page or a bit of content on top of any page a visitor hits on my site. For example, a user comes to my site and after 4 seconds all the page content moves down and displays whatever I specify. So I could in fact have `google.com` show up and push down my page or `facebook.com` or a big photo of my smiling face. :)

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use JQuery to achieve this.

See an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mFwmy/)

```
$(function() {
    var wait=2000; //ms to wait

    setTimeout(function() {
        var popdown=$("<div style='background-color:red; border:1px solid black; display:none'>Whatever you want to popdown</div>");

        $('html').prepend(popdown);
        $(popdown).slideDown();
    }, wait);
});​
```

Comment: thanks Michael. How would i add a whole site/iframe?  seems to do what I need so far.

Comment: You would just use `var popdown=$("<iframe src='http://www.w3schools.com'> </iframe>");`  but Google and others don't allow iframes access to their sites.